# smallestWidth: Is this a typo in Android Documentation on Resources?

Tags: android

Quoting from `smallestWidth` section of [Resources Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) of Android:

> Thus, the value you use should be the actual smallest dimension required by your layout (usually, this value is the "smallest width" that your layout supports, regardless of the screen's current orientation).

```
Some values you might use here for common screen sizes:

320, for devices with screen configurations such as:
    240x320 ldpi (QVGA handset)
    320x480 mdpi (handset)
    480x800 hdpi (high density handset) <- IS THIS A TYPO ?
```

Why would a  480x800 hdpi (high density handset) draw its resources from res/layout-sw320dp folder. Looks like a typo but i may be missing something.

Comment: no... "smallest width", for a 480*800, device is 480. Width depends on orientation. So "smallest width" is the width when the device is in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "smallest width", for a 480*800 device, is 480.
The width depends on orientation.
So the "smallest width" is the width when the device is in portrait mode.